# Build android app from android.mk project

Tags: android

I have a project which has no gradle, only android.mk file and i need to generate apk for this project.

How can I do that?

I have alreadey have ndk-build. but ndk build can generate only .so file.

```
    LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := sss
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/res
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)

LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES := telephony-common ims-common

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
    volley \
    gson \
    json

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES=gson:libs/gson.jar
include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES=json:libs/json.jar
include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: What prevents you using _Android Studio_?

Comment: there is no gradle file

Comment: android project cant recognize

Comment: And what does this Android.mk look like? If it doesn't contain any rule to build an APK then it wasn't intended to be used for that.

Comment: run button is greyed out

Comment: you can look into mk file

Comment: Where did this come from? It looks like something that might be meant to be built as part of Android itself, not as a third-party app.

Comment: @Micheal its rom code :) a service app